# How to get different data from a dynamically render input field react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I have state,

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    semester: '',
    credit: '',
    sgpa: ''
})
```

I have taken an input field where user can give his value.According to the user input dynamicallyinputfield will be created.So here my issue is 'I want different data from each dynamically created field'.How can I achive that?

[Screenshot of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg3zq.png)

my whole component is,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import cal from "./image/bgimg.jpg";

function Home() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    semester: "",
    credit: "",
    sgpa: "",
  });
  const [noOfSem, setNoOfSem] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    let sems = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < state?.semester; index++) {
      sems.push(index + 1);
    }
    console.log(sems);
    setNoOfSem(sems);
  };
  const emptySemester = () => {
    setState({ ...state, semester: "" });
    setNoOfSem([]);
  };
  const handleCgpaSubmit = () => {
    console.log(state.credit, state.sgpa);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <img src={cal} alt="" className="imgcal img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div className="col-md">
            <div className="form1">
              <div className="col-md formmain">
                <input
                  type="number"
                  value={state?.semester}
                  name="semester"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  placeholder="Enter Total Semester"
                />
                {noOfSem.length === 0 ? (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-success btn333"
                    onClick={handleClick}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                ) : (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-success btn333"
                    onClick={emptySemester}
                  >
                    Reset Semester
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="col form2">
                {noOfSem?.map((item, index) => (
                  <>
                    <div className="col-md seminpt">
                      <label htmlFor="">Semester {index + 1}</label>
                      <input
                        type="Number"
                        name="credit"
                        value={state.credit}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        placeholder="Total Credit"
                      />
                      <input
                        type="Number"
                        name="sgpa"
                        value={state.sgpa}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        placeholder={`SGPA sem${index + 1}`}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </>
                ))}
                {noOfSem.length > 0 && (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-success btn3334"
                    onClick={handleCgpaSubmit}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

'I want different data from each dynamically created field'.How can I achive that?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I changed the input for the number of semester to have a ref, since there is no need to update a state everytime you change the input. When calling `handleClick` it will take the value of the input and update `noOfSem`.

The `handleChange` takes in a semester index, this will help keep track of which data belongs to which semester. We return a new state with and override the `prevState` on the given `semesterIndex`.

When rendering the we just create a new array the size of `noOfSem`. Getting the values from the state we simply pass in the `semesterIndex` and pick the property we want.

```js
function Home() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const [noOfSem, setNoOfSem] = useState(0);
  const semesterNumberInputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleChange = (e, semesterIndex) => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [semesterIndex]: {
          ...prevState[semesterIndex],
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        },
      };
    });
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!semesterNumberInputRef.current) return;
    const newNumberOfSemesters = Number(semesterNumberInputRef.current.value);
    setNoOfSem(newNumberOfSemesters);
  };

  const emptySemester = () => {
    setState({});
    setNoOfSem(0);
  };

  const handleCgpaSubmit = () => {
    console.log(state);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div className="col-md">
            <div className="form1">
              <div className="col-md formmain">
                <input
                  ref={semesterNumberInputRef}
                  type="number"
                  name="semester"
                  placeholder="Enter Total Semester"
                />
                {noOfSem === 0 ? (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-success btn333"
                    onClick={handleClick}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                ) : (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-success btn333"
                    onClick={emptySemester}
                  >
                    Reset Semester
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="col form2">
                {new Array(noOfSem).fill(null).map((_, index) => {
                  const semesterIndex = index + 1; // add one since the index starts at 0
                  return (
                    <div
                      className="col-md seminpt"
                      key={`semester-input-${index}`}
                    >
                      <label>Semester {index + 1}</label>
                      <input
                        type="number"
                        name="credit"
                        value={state[semesterIndex]?.credit || ""}
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, semesterIndex)}
                        placeholder="Total Credit"
                      />
                      <input
                        type="number"
                        name="sgpa"
                        value={state[semesterIndex]?.sgpa || ""}
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, semesterIndex)}
                        placeholder={`SGPA sem${semesterIndex}`}
                      />
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
                {noOfSem > 0 && (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-success btn3334"
                    onClick={handleCgpaSubmit}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`handleCgpaSumbit` will log this as result, an object with the number of the semester as index and the according data.

```js
{
  "1": {
    "credit": "20",
    "sgpa": "10"
  },
  "2": {
    "credit": "21",
    "sgpa": "9"
  },
  "3": {
    "credit": "13",
    "sgpa": "6"
  },
  "4": {
    "credit": "8",
    "sgpa": "6"
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you with your project!